# Remote Performance Counters System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter, system.diagnostics

I've got 2 segments of code who sporadically throw errors. If I run the application locally on the server defined in the server.FullyQualifiedDomainName, I get no errors, never. If I run the application remotely and read the counters via the network, I will get the errors defined below. The errors don't happen all the time. I've read somewhere reading performance counters over a network is kinda shaky... Anyway to get more reliable responses?

Code to read categories:

```
var windowsCounterCategory = new PerformanceCounterCategory(counterCategory, server.FullyQualifiedDomainName); 
var serviceGuidsStr = windowsCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames();
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not Read Category Index: 8324.
   at System.Diagnostics.CategorySample..ctor(Byte[] data, CategoryEntry entry, PerformanceCounterLib library)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetCategorySample(String category)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetCategorySample(String machine, String category)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCounterInstances(String categoryName, String machineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames()
```

Code to read counter values:

```
   using (var perfomanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, counterName, instanceId, Service.Server.FullyQualifiedDomainName))
   {
      var counterValue = perfomanceCounter.RawValue;
      log.Trace("Read counter value " + counterValue.ToString());
      return counterValue;
   }
```

Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not Read Category Index: 8324.
   at System.Diagnostics.CategorySample..ctor(Byte[] data, CategoryEntry entry, PerformanceCounterLib library)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetCategorySample(String category)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetCategorySample(String machine, String category)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.NextSample()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.get_RawValue()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like reading performance counters over a network is simply not super reliable. I've decided to use the Microsoft Transient Fault Handling library (v 6.0, search topaz on nuget) and implemented a retry strategy. Usually one retry is enough to get a valid answer (no exeception), sometimes it might take 2 retries.

I implemented a transient fault detection strategy that checks for that specific network related error (`System.InvalidOperationException: Could not Read Category Index: 8324.`)

```
public class PerformanceCounterStrategy : ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy
{
  public bool IsTransient(Exception ex)
  {
    return ex.GetType() == typeof (InvalidOperationException);
  }
}
```

Here is the retry strategy I implemented:

```
var retryStrategy = new Incremental(3, 2, 2);
var retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<PerformanceCounterTransientStrategy>(retryStrategy);

retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() =>
  {
    var windowsCounterCategory = new PerformanceCounterCategory(counterCategory, server.FQDN);
    var guidsStr = windowsCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames();

  });
```